# is this query possible in active-record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have a User class which has a column called 'device' of type VARCHAR(255). This column basically contains the device types, for example string 'iPhone 4S', 'iPod Touch 4G', etc...

Is it possible (without loading ALL users and manually doing it) to figure out the total number of occurrences of each device?

So it would return:

```
iPhone:  50
iPad 2: 54
etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just do this:

```
counts = User.count(:group => :device)
```

That would translate (more or less) to this SQL:

```
select count(*), device from users group by device
```

and you'd get a Hash mapping `device` to the count in `counts`:

```
{
    'iPhone' => 50,
    'iPad 2' => 54,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You've helped me out before, really appreciate it.